# Get a count of one column based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following data. I am trying to the number a count of each buyer_id by acct_id where the buyer_id contains 5. So for acct 51, which has five instances and contains one with 5, I was to find a count of each buyer_id (excluding 5 of course). This count should go through all acct_id's which contain a buyer_id with 5, and provide a count of all the other buyer_id's.

```
acct_id        buyer_id         message
51              5            success   
51              13           fail   
51              4            success
51              6            success
51              9            fail
53              6            fail   
53              12           fail   
53              4            success
57              6            fail   
57              12           fail   
57              4            success
57              5            success
```

So in this example I'd end up with something like below

```
buyer_id    count(*)
4           2     
5           2  
6           2
9           1 
12          1
13          1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why count for buyer_id=6 is 2?

Comment: Yes I see some inconsistencies in your example or I don't understand what you want.

Comment: It's 2 because I want to only count(buyer_id) when an acct_id is associated with a buyer_id of 5.

Comment: So in other words, because acct_id 53 doesn't have a buyer_id of 5 among it, you do not count any of the buyer_id's for acct 53.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select buyer_id, count(distinct acct_id)
from Table1 a
where exists (
  select * from Table1
  where acct_id = a.acct_id 
    and buyer_id =5)
group by buyer_id
```

See the sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d3d2/3

Comment: remove `and buyer_id = 5` to match the answer with question title. 5 is requirement of the user but not mentioned in title.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
Select buyer_id, count(*)
From table
Where acct_id in (Select acct_id From table Where buyer_id = 5) --insert buyer_id param here
Group By buyer_id
```